# Install Magento 2 Extensions on localhost?

Tags: magento2, extensions

Is it possible to install Magento 2 extensions on localhost?

I currently have the latest version 2.2.3 on Windows 10 using XAMPP but when trying to install an extension, it fails due to cron job not running.

Comment: yes, you can install in localhost. What is the error?? Which extension do you want to install.

Comment: @BornCoder it is an extension called 'Slider' which is free: https://marketplace.magento.com/sy-slider.html - the errors are: http://i.cubeupload.com/WPGYxN.png - could I manually install it?

Comment: If you want to install this extension manually, follow instructions on their GitHub page : [Slider-M2](https://github.com/SlavaYurthev/Slider-M2/wiki). 2 choices : with [composer](https://github.com/SlavaYurthev/Slider-M2/wiki#composer-installation-via-github) or by [download and copy](https://github.com/SlavaYurthev/Slider-M2/wiki#instalation)

Comment: @urbansurfers Thanks, I noticed it yesterday and managed to get it installed

Answer (score 0):

You don't need CronJob to install your extensions in local.
(there is no cron on Windows OS anyway).

If you really need a working CronJob, you have to use the **Windows Task Scheduler**.

Official link here : [Windows Start Task Scheduler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc721931(v=ws.11))

Comment: I've replied to 'BornCoder' above on this issue, it looks like the cron job is stopping it.. if I had PHP errors as the screenshot suggests, surely I wouldn't of been able to install Magento 2 in the first place...